# How do I make this work and make it save when I quit and resume when reloaded

Tags: java, android, function, save

Right ive now got my button counter working and it will increment when clicked but my problem now is it wont save so when it reopens it will start fresh again.... ill put my code below but any help adding the save function to it would be greatly appreciated!

```
package com.example.counter;

import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import         android.view.View.OnClickListener; import android.widget.Button; import     android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Private member field to keep track of the count
private int mCount = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
final Button countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCount++;
        countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
    }
});

}
}
```

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:text="Count" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload the onPause method and save the variable using the SharedPreferences Class. You will also need to overload the onResume method to re-load that value into mCount.

Please Read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: just had a read of those websites you two gave me and its confused me again :P without trying to sound like a muppet could you edit the code to do it? I know that sounds really bad but I honestly dont know what I'm doing

Comment: Hey James, updated the code. Please take another look at it. Add this to your MainActivity class.

Comment: hey thanks for the code, from the original code where abouts do i have to replace it? Ive tried a couple of spots but every time I do it, it errors.

Comment: Just after `private int mCount = 0;`

Comment: ok ive got it copied and pasted where you said and it crashes :(

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you. its the easiest way to store data
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

You would read the counter data at onCreate and save it at onPause so it restores nicely when your user opens the app again. More details at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Dont save the counter each time your button is clicked, it will incur in excessive I/O for your simple task, draining battery.

Comment: just had a read of those websites you two gave me and its confused me again :P without trying to sound like a muppet could you edit the code to do it? I know that sounds really bad but I honestly dont know what I'm doing

Comment: Edited Montycarlo's answer to correct some slight mistakes, use it. It will work wonders